# Specializations of the function .Difference between pointer typename and string?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T>
int compare(T a, T b) {
    return (a < b) ? 1 :(a > b) ? -1 : 0;
}

template<typename T>
int compare(T* a, T* b) {
    return (*a < *b) ? 1 :(*a > * b) ? -1 : 0;
}
template<>
int compare<string>(string a, string b) {
    return  (a < b) ? 1 : (a > b) ? -1 : 0;
}


 int main(){
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    compare("Hello", "World"); //1
    compare(&a, &b); //2
 }
```

Issue: Function **int compare(T* a, T* b)** is calling for **first** and **second** case;

DOD: Call function **int compare(string a, string b)** for **first** case;

Comment: Are you sure this compiles? Partial specializations for functions are not allowed in C++, so the `T*`version shouldn't compile.

Comment: can you specify a compiler version you used?

Comment: This obviously isn't a complete example (`main` is missing for instance) but I suspect the real example uses a `T*` overload, not a specialization.

Comment: Yes, I did not compile. I changed the code. And add main(). But can not cat admirable result.

Answer (score 0):

`"Hello"` is a `const char[6]`. When used as an argument, that's a better match for `const char*` than for `std::string`. The latter is a user-defined conversion.

Solution:

```
using namespace std::literals;
compare("Hello"s, "World"s);
```

These are `std::string` literals

Comment: Your solution does not call partial specialization for "Hello". It calls general specialization